# QlikView Resources

Tags: business-intelligence, data-analysis, qlikview

I want to add Qlikview Development to my skill-set. I have a C# and SQl background. Are there any free online resources to getting me going at developer level not end-user? What's the best starting place for me and the level of difficulty involved.

I am looking for resources that can help me to expert level. One resource I found is the Udemy course and if anyone has done it please share your review of the course content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can find good videos on youtube (like this one:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef_BigFXCis).
- When you install qlikview, you have there a qlikview tutorial directory. Follow the pdf file and do everything on that pdf. it is very extensive, but after that you can start developing intermediate solutions. The PDF actually covers the whole QV official course.
- After that, go to the [qlikview cookbook](http://qlikviewcookbook.com/) site and start exploring more possibilities.
- Find more blogs on QV and subscribe to them.
- QV community is amazing. use it!

Qlikview is relatively easy to "get" at first, but don't be fooled by its simplicity - its a whole platform. I've been developing in QV 7 years now and still learn something new once in a while.

And I have to say it - its a very good choice! QV is amazing and very popular.
There isn't much I couldn't do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the links very helpful. I must admit it's an amazing tool to learn can't wait to use it.